# Recursive function returns unexpected result

Tags: c++, c

My funciton takes a number input from the user and recursively sums the number 'n' to one.
Inputting a 5 would sum 1/5 + 1/4 + 1/3+ 1/2 + 1/1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
//to 
float recursion(float num,float sum);
void main(void)
{
  float num=5,sum=0;
  //input num
  printf("%d",recursion(num,sum));

  getch();
}
 
float recursion(float num,float sum)
{
  // int sum=0; every time u run it the sum is assigned 0
  if( num==1)
    return 1;
  else
  {
    sum=sum+(1/num);
    num--;
    recursion(num,sum);
  }
  return sum;
}//recursion function ends
```

The problem is, that it is giving 0. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: State your question in the body of the question so your question doesn't get closed.

Comment: Did you try to check what happens in debugger? there is a trivial mistake. but you should try to solve it yourself before asking such questions.

Comment: @spender, does it matter? He's obviously trying on his own and has hit a problem. He's not asking us to do his homework for him.

Comment: The answer you get from the above function is 0.2, but since you're printing it using %d it takes the integer part of it and hence you get 0. To see a working implementation check my answer.

Comment: What's a funciton?  Is that one o' them thar new comp sci thangs, like monads and functors?

Comment: I've made changes in your code with explanation of the changes as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why's the `printf("%d")` while it's supposed to print a float? Doesn't that display an integer making it always 0 for a float less than 0?

```
float recursion(float num)
{
    if( num==1.0f)
    {
        printf("1/1 = ");
        return 1.0f;
    }
    float inverse = 1.0f/num;
    printf("1/%.0f + ", num);
    return (inverse + recursion(--num));
}//recursion function ends
```

Here's the test code:

```
float num=5,sum=0;
float expected = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
{
    expected += 1.0f/i;
}
//input num
printf("Expected %f and got %f",expected, recursion(num));
```

Output:
`1/5 + 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/1 = Expected 2.283334 and got 2.283334`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You should return the result of the recursive call:

```
return recursion(num,sum);
```

instead of `return sum`.

Comment: And `%d` should be changed to `%f`.

Comment: +1. I think this is at least one of the bigger problems the OP is having. There's nothing wrong with the division.

Comment: @tanacius but i think that a function just returns only 1 value

Comment: but the answer shdnt be 0.2 it should be giving 2.28

Comment: @fahad ... yes, it does. You can just delete the line `return sum;` because it will never be reached. Right now you calculate only 1/5 - which is 0.2 and showed is 0, because you use `%d` instead of `%f`

Comment: but i want to calulate the 2.28 not 0.2 :S

Comment: @fahad: If you change your function to return the result of the recursion like tanascius said, you will get 2.28. And if you also change the print statement like tur1ng said, you will also see it. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

```
float recursion(float num) {
  if( num==1) 
    return 1; 
  return (1.0/num) + recursion(num - 1);
}
```

By the way, do not input a negative number!

Answer (score 0):

@fahad: Changes in your code has been commented in the code below:

```
float recursion2(float num,float sum)
{
    // int sum=0; every time u run it the sum is assigned 0
    if( num==1)
        // Vite Falcon: Needs to return sum + 1
        return sum + 1.0f;
    else
    {
        // Vite Falcon: This is not really necessary.
        //sum=sum+(1/num);
        float inverse = 1.0f/num;
        num--;
        // Vite Falcon: The new sum is returned by the recursive function and so
        // should be stored and returned.
        sum = recursion2(num,sum + inverse);
    }
    return sum;
}//recursion function ends
```

PS: Sorry I had to answer again because I don't know how to add multi-line code as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sum=sum+(1.0/num);`. When you divide 1, an integer with a float, the float gets converted to integer first.

Comment: I believe the divide operator, when giving a floating point operand and an integral operand, will automatically return a floating-point result.

Comment: See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Type_Casting (section promotion / denotion)

Answer (score -1):

```
float recursion(int num) {
  if (num == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  return 1 / num + recursion(num--);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will always return 0 due to integer division.

Comment: This is actually undefined behavior (using `num` and `num--` without a sequence point between them). And even if it wasn't, it wouldn't do what you want because num would be the same in each recursive call.